Flutter UpgradeAlert not work for ios and android both
I am trying to use upgrader package but it not work for me.
below is my sample code
  return MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: UpgradeAlert(
            showIgnore: false,
            showLater: false,
            dialogStyle:UpgradeDialogStyle.cupertino,
            child: const SplashScreen(),
          ),
          builder: (context, child) {
            child = EasyLoading.init()(context,child);
            child = MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(1.0),boldText: false),
              child: child,
            );
            return child;
          },
        );


You have to newer version of your app in Appstore.

"it not work for me" is hard to help with. What's the problem? Any error message?

no any error , app update is live in app store but not detect on app
